# Confusion about generic bounded wildcard types

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Pretty trivial Java question. This code has an error:

```
public abstract class SubTypeDependentEditor<T> implements Editor<T> {
  protected abstract Editor<? extends T> getEditorFor(T obj);       

  public void edit(T obj) {
    Editor<? extends T> editor = getEditorFor(obj);
    editor.edit(obj); // ERROR IS HERE
  }
}
```

What's the right way one should fix it?

The idea of `T` is basically just a type of classes' hierarchy root, so given a hierarchy like this:

```
class Entity {}
class EntityA extends Entity {}
class EntityB extends Entity {}
```

one will have `T` set to `Entity` and `getEditorFor(T obj)` is responsible for returning `Editor<X>` where `X` depends on `obj`'s concrete type and always Is-A `T`. So, if you have `SubTypeDependentEditor<Entity>`, `getEditorFor(T obj)` returns `Editor<EntityA>` when `obj` is `EntityA` and `Editor<EntityB>` when `obj` is `EntityB`.

Any chance this can be implemented without warnings?

Update:

```
protected abstract Editor<? extends T> getEditorFor(T obj);
```

Can basically have any other signature, but the code that implements that code only has objects that are `Editor<X>`, so in case this method returns `Editor<T>` I'm not sure how to implement `getEditorFor(T obj)`.

Comment: What is the error that the code gives?

Comment: What's your rationale for using wildcards (`? extends T`) in some places instead of just `T` throughout?

Comment: What error does the compiler actually say? Is the method `edit` defined in the `Editor` interface?

Comment: What is the signature of `Editor.edit`?

Comment: @chrisbunney: `The method edit(capture#2-of ? extends T) in the type App.Editor<capture#2-of ? extends T> is not applicable for the arguments (T)`

Comment: @KublaiKhan: Please review updated question.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Please review the code there's an implementation for `edit()`

Comment: @loki2302, I see that.  I just wanted to check that you haven't generalized it from the `Editor` interface.

Comment: If you must allow generalised `Editor`s, instead of using `? super T` you might want to create a proxy `Editor` so the client doesn't have to deal with wildcards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected abstract Editor<? extends T> getEditorFor(T obj);
```

means that `getEditorFor()` returns an editor for an unknown sub-type of T.

You can't pass use any value of type `T` with that result since the compiler cannot prove that `obj` works with the same concrete sub-type of `T` that is `obj`'s type.

The solution is to change

```
protected abstract Editor<? extends T> getEditorFor(T obj);
```

to

```
protected abstract Editor<? super T> getEditorFor(T obj);
```

which says that `getEditorFor` returns an editor that edits an unknown type that includes `obj`.